# Why did sleep cause my script to execute correctly?

Tags: linux, cron

I am using a VM of debian11 on a Windows 10 IoT enterprise host to handle an incoming data stream from some sensors. I have a relatively simple shell file to log data that I'm initiating from a cron line, the cron line was originally

```
@reboot /program.sh
```

This shell file (program.sh) itself ends with the following two lines after some cleanup.

```
upload.sh
start_program.sh
```

upload.sh looks in the output folder (created during the main start_program) and uploads any output files to google drive and then deletes them (it is skipped with no issue if this is the first time running the program or no output exists). Start_program then starts the data loggers

A key component of this data logging system is that it must be able to withstand a loss of power, hence the @reboot in cron (I have altered the power management in the systems BIOS to also auto restart on the power reset). When I tested this by closing down the virtual machine and opening it again it all works fine, data is uploaded and the program is initiated again. However when I turned the PC off and on at the plug the VM booted up (using a .bat file that calls VBoxmanage) and the data got uploaded, however the data loggers did not start. i.e upload.sh ran but program_start.sh didn't.

It took abit of trial and error to figure out that this was happening, and I reasoned that as the only actual difference between the two trial environments was the PC being turned on again, that maybe there was a background process preventing the data logger starting, I changed the cron line to this

```
@reboot sleep 60 && /program.sh
```

This has fixed my problem, now after cycling the PC's power the data will upload and the logging start, however I'm still not entirely sure why and if this is a permanent fix so any insight would be appreciated

Comment: " upload.sh ran but program_start.sh didn't." You'd have to check your program logs to see why.  It seems likely your program has some dependency, maybe on networking?  And doesn't handle the error case and restarting well.  This is one reason cron is a poor choice for managing system services.  Systemd would be a better choice.  It's pretty easy to write a systemd unit, then you can specify dependencies like networking and systemd will handle it.  https://wiki.debian.org/systemd/Services looks pretty legit, but systemd is not debian specific - any tutorial should help.